# ajax toolkit image upload is not happening

Tags: ajax

i have one ajaxtoolkit file upload on the page

```
<ajax:HtmlEditorExtender runat="server" ID="htmEditor" 

DisplaySourceTab="true" TargetControlID="txtWelcomenote"  

OnImageUploadComplete="htmEdtior_OnUploadComplete">
```

and code behind is

```
protected void htmEdtior_OnUploadComplete(object sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
        {
            // Generate file path
            string filePath = "~/Images/" + e.FileName;

            // Save uploaded file to the file system
            var ajaxFileUpload = (AjaxFileUpload)sender;
            ajaxFileUpload.SaveAs(MapPath(filePath));

            // Update client with saved image path
            e.PostedUrl = Page.ResolveUrl(filePath);
        }
```

And my question is 
while i am trying to upload an image, it is not getting upload
and the event is also not firing. and i have debugged also from that 
i am grtting extra query string like **contextkey={DA8BEDC8-B952-4d5d-8CC2-59FE922E2923}**
what could be the problem?? and what is the solution? Please some on help me

Comment: The following article could be helpful: http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27163.

You can also double check whether the problem is not related to URL rewriter or routing.